# Update variable if it is duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO myNotes ('id','date','notes') VALUES ('$id','$date','$notes')";
```

I want to insert the informations bellow using php into mysql database but at the same time i want to check if the date and id already exists then update the notes

For those who search for the solution I found it

```
$sql = "SELECT notes FROM myNotes WHERE id='$id' AND  date='$date'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $sql = "UPDATE myNotes SET notes=$notes WHERE id='$id' AND date='$date'";
   if ($conn->query($sql)) {
       echo 'successfully updated';
 }
else {
   echo 'failed';}
   };}
else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO myNotes (id,date,notes) VALUES ('$id','$date','$note')";
 if ($conn->query($sql)) {
     echo 'added successfully';
 }
 else {
     echo 'failed to add';
 };}
```

Comment: Please do not abuse the code snippet tool. It is for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript only.

Comment: you're using the wrong [identifier qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) in your query

Comment: `echo "erreur";` did not help you here, `mysqli_error($con)` will.

Comment: You're also open to a serious sql injection.

Comment: I'm asking about the query not the result

Comment: `INSERT INTO myNotes ('id','date','notes')` failed; I said it up there in comments about the identifier qualifiers. If you're asking about something and posting code that already doesn't work... then keep going with the answer given; it too (in its present state) failed.

Comment: Because the localhost and the password are rong,and it's not my question if  the code has error or not

Comment: ....err... what?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO myNotes ('id','date','notes') VALUES ('$id','$date','$notes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE notes='updatednotes', date='updateddate'";
```

Comment: and what is the updatednotes

Comment: You told you want to update notes and date if found

Comment: no update note with the new value if id and date was found